# Regex: Contains a word, doesn't contain another word

Tags: java, regex

I'm unsuccessfully trying to find a solution to this problem:
**To find a Java regex that can recognize a String containing one word and not containing another word**.

To be more clear, as an example, let's check if my sentence to contains "method" and do not contains "efficient" as whole words (meaning it has not to be part of another word). The regex matcher should return, e.g.,:

```
This method was efficient.      false   (contains "method", but contains "efficient")
This method was unefficient.    true    (cont. "method" doesn't cont. "efficient")
This method was simple.         true    (cont. "method" doesn't cont. "efficient")
This routine is efficient       false   (cont. "efficient" but no "method")
```

What I've tried so far, at least the more nearest solution results.

```
( method )(?!.*efficient.*)      Almost there, but "unefficient" also triggers.
( method )(?!.* efficient .*)    No. Now " method " doesn't trigger anymore.
((.*method.*)(?!.*efficient.*))  No. the absence of "efficient" doesn't trigger.
```

So it seems to be a problem of exact word match. So I also tried at first:

```
 (.*\bmethod\b.*)(?!.*efficient.*)
```

Also to not to depend on spaces to bound each word.
But nothing. I tried almost the whole day and it's painful.

I am using
http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html
as a reference website, and
http://regexpal.com/
for testing.

Thank you!
D.

Comment: Why don't you use [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence))?

Comment: Good question. I want to perform a check by a table set of complex parsing Strings. For example (in metalanguage):

(+word1)(-word2) -> Action1;

((+word1)(-word3)||(word4)) -> Action2;

Comment: What Maroun said or just `(?s)^(?=.*\\bmethod\\b)(?!.*\\befficient\\b)`. `(?s)` is to set the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.`

Comment: @donnadulcinea You can still achieve this by using `contains(something) || !contains(somethingElse)`

Comment: @MarounMaroun: It doesn't check for word boundary, though.

Comment: What do you want as a result for "The efficient method didn't work"? This is a Hammer/Nail problem.  You have a hammer (regex) and want to use it to solve your nailing problem.  This is not a nailing problem. You are trying to use Regular Expressions for a non-regular grammar. I recommend you write a real parser based on some simple punctuation rules to find word boundaries and extract the words.

Comment: Yes @JimGarrison that's also my conclusion. My parser works fine. I supposed with regex I could have a more powerful ruleset and a simplified code. But seems this is not the case. ty! Btw -The efficient method didn't work- shall return false, and it's ok, but for more than three words this starts being too messy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to refine your first approach (`( method )(?!.*efficient.*)`).

You already said `Almost there`, so why not take this approach a bit further? I just added a word-boundary `\b` before `efficient`, so it won't exclude `unefficient`:

```
^.+(method)(?!.*\befficient.*)
```

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/gR5hE8)

---

Now there's one thing left:

```
this is an efficient method
```

would still be an unwanted match (I suppose).

So you can add the look-ahead in front of your main-group to get rid of this match.

```
^(?!.*\befficient.*).*(method)
```

[demo @ regex101](http://regex101.com/r/tV2kM8)

---

In order to match `efficient` exactly you should add another word-boundary, otherwise it will match on `efficients`, too:

```
^(?!.*\befficient\b).*(\bmethod)
```

If you want to make `method` an exact match, too, just add another boundary after it. For now this would match on `methods`.

Comment: Thanks you for all answer.
I refined this one a little:
    <code>^(?!.*\befficient.*).+(\bmethod)(?!.*\befficient.*)</code>

so that also "method" has to be exact match. The problem remains for the ending.

    <pre>this are efficients method</pre>     should be true

because word efficient is not exact match.

I think the easiest solution for my parses is to split the rule sets and check them in and. I'll try later as my brain rests for a while!  (--->Sorry four spaces markdown doesn't work here for me!)

Comment: @donnadulcinea If you want to exclude `efficients`, too, so making it really only match on `efficient` then you can just add another word-boundary after `efficient`: `\befficient\b`. So your whole regex would then look like: `^(?!.*\befficient\b.*).+(\bmethod)(?!.*\befficient\b.*)`

Comment: I just tried before and it didn't work, maybe I did some mistake writing. Yours work!!! Thank you @Basti M.
Since the order still counts I think I can't exploit regex for this kind of parsing (I shall have complex rules) but this was an interesting lesson.

Comment: `^(?!.*\befficient\b.*).+(\bmethod)(?!.*\befficient\b.*)` The second check for `efficient` is redundant, and checking for trailing `.*` is also redundant. And you are disallowing `method` to start the string.

Comment: @nhahtdh you're right. it may be rewritten to `^(?!.*\befficient).*(\bmethod\b)`, i will edit this into my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
^(?=.*\bmethod\b)(?!.*\befficient\b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\bmethod\\b)?.*(\\befficient\\b)?";
Matcher m = p.matcher("The method is unefficient.");
if (m.find() 
     && ((m.group(1) == null) != (m.group(2) == null))) {
     // found exactly 1 word.
     ...
}
else // found 0 or 2 words.
```

The only restriction is that the words will have to appear in that order.
But this can be resolved by adding an alternative that looks the same except the
words are switched. And then group 3 and 4 must not both be not null or null